# How can i use a where clause within a select statement in linq. (ie. on a property.)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this linq query:

```
var sku = (from a in con.MagentoStockBalances
           join b in con.MFGParts on a.SKU equals b.mfgPartKey
           join c in con.DCInventory_Currents on b.mfgPartKey equals c.mfgPartKey
           where a.SKU != 0 && c.dcKey ==6
           select new
           {
               Part_Number = b.mfgPartNumber,
               Stock = a.stockBalance,
               Recomended = a.RecomendedStock,
               Cato = c.totalOnHandQuantity
           }).ToList();
```

Now i need to remove the c.dcKey ==6 condition and have something like this:

```
var sku = (from a in con.MagentoStockBalances
           join b in con.MFGParts on a.SKU equals b.mfgPartKey
           join c in con.DCInventory_Currents on b.mfgPartKey equals c.mfgPartKey
           where a.SKU != 0
           select new
           {
               Part_Number = b.mfgPartNumber,
               Stock = a.stockBalance,
               Recomended = a.RecomendedStock,
               Cato = c.totalOnHandQuantity where c.dcKey == 6,
              Kerry = c.totalOnHandQuantity where c.dcKey == 7
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: Whats the problem then? I don't understand the issue

Comment: What's the problem? That is exactly how you use `where`.

Comment: @AnnArbor87: This won't even compile.

Comment: he added the where in the select.  You could use a conditional operator

Comment: What should be the value of `Cato` when `c.dcKey != 6`?

Comment: @svick I need both values. The totalOnHandQuantity of c.dcKey == 6 and the totalOnHandQuantity of c.dcKey == 7 each stored in separate variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Cato = c.dcKey == 6 ? c.totalOnHandQuantity : 0,
Kerry = c.dcKey == 7 ? c.totalOnHandQuantity : 0
```

The ?: syntax is called a conditional operator.

Comment: Actually this worked with a little tweaking in my query. Thanks, you are the man!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding another `join`, I would use a separate query in a `let`:

```
from a in con.MagentoStockBalances
join b in con.MFGParts on a.SKU equals b.mfgPartKey
where a.SKU != 0
let cs = con.DCInventory_Currents.Where(c => b.mfgPartKey == c.mfgPartKey)
select new
{
    Part_Number = b.mfgPartNumber,
    Stock = a.stockBalance,
    Recomended = a.RecomendedStock,
    Cato = cs.Single(c => c.dcKey == 6).totalOnHandQuantity 
    Kerry = cs.Single(c => c.dcKey == 7).totalOnHandQuantity 
}
```

Though I have no idea how well will LINQ to SQL handle a query like this (if it handles it at all).

Answer (score -1):

```
var query= from x in context.a 
       where String.IsNullOrEmpty(param1) || (x.p == param1 && x.i == param2)
        select x;
```

Comment: What? How is this relevant to the question?